# Similar functionality like masksToBounds in IOS for android

Tags: java, android, ios

I have a RelativeLayout with multiple child layouts and widgets. If I set the background drawable of the parent layout to a shape with rounded corners then the child layouts are not masked to their parent.

In iOS the CALayer of a UIView has attribute `masksToBounds`. If this attribute is set to true all subviews are masked to the shape of this view.

Is there a similar functionality in a Android Layout?

Comment: there is a clipchildren property

Comment: Since Android 5.0 (Lollipop) you can set an `Outline` on a `View` which clips it and its children. Before Android 5.0 there was no such functionality.